# Recursive numeric equality in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, equality, r5rs

It seems that Scheme considers integer and floating point versions of a number to be different when using equal?, but the same when using = to compare them:

```
(equal? 2 2.0)  ; => #f
(= 2 2.0)       ; => #t
```

However, if I have a recursive structure with some numeric parts (or even a simple list of numbers), is there a method to compare them that uses = for numeric comparisons?

```
(equal? '(2 3) '(2.0 3.0))  ; => #f
(= '(2 3) '(2.0 3.0))       ; error: contract violation
```

I can write my own equality checker, something like this:

```
(define myequal?
  (lambda (x y)
    (cond ((and (null? x) (null? y)) #t)
          ((or (null? x) (null? y)) #f)
          ((and (pair? x) (pair? y))
           (and (myequal? (car x) (car y))
                (myequal? (cdr x) (cdr y))))
          ((or (pair? x) (pair? y)) #f)
          ((and (number? x) (number? y)) (= x y))
          ((or (number? x) (number? y)) #f)
          (else (equal? x y)))))
```

But it seems like this would be a common enough task that Scheme might have a builtin method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Racket you can build the notion of equality that you want with the help of the [`equal?/recur`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Equality.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._equal%7E3f%2Frecur%29%29) built-in procedure:

```
;; equalish? : Any Any -> Boolean
;; Like equal?, but use = for numbers (including within compound data)
(define (equalish? a b)
  (if (and (number? a) (number? b))
      (= a b)
      (equal?/recur a b equalish?)))

(equalish? '(2 3) '(2.0 3.0))
;; => #t
```

The `equal?/recur` procedure handles recurring through pairs, structures, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Scheme is a minimalistic language and have very few primitives. `2` and `2.0` are not the same number because `2.0` can be lower and higher than `2` which is the exact amount `2`.

If you have a list with numbers and wish to check if all are the same with `=` you can do it using [`every`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#every) from [SRFI-1 List Library](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html):

```
;; include the library. In R5RS this is impleentation specific
;; and worst case you need to load of external file to be portable.
(load "srfi1.scm") 

(every = '(2 3) '(2.0 3.0)) ; ==> #t
```

In R6RS it gets simpler:

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base)
        (only (srfi :1) every))

(every = '(2 3) '(2.0 3.0)) ; ==> #t
```

And since you have tagged Racket there is a chance that you might not write Scheme but perhaps `#lang racket` which has both support for SRFI-1 and its own version of `every` that is called [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=andmap#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29):

```
#lang racket

(andmap = '(2 3) '(2.0 3.0)) ; ==> #t

(require srfi/1)
(every = '(2 3) '(2.0 3.0)) ; ==> #t
```

**EDIT**

A generic solution for all tree structures that use itself for tree structure and `equal?` when there are no more type specific options:

```
(define (make-equal . predicates-and-equal-procedures)
  (when (odd? (length predicates-and-equal-procedures))
    (error "make-equal needs an even number of predicate and equal function arguments"))

  (define (mequal? a b)
    (if (pair? a)
        (and (pair? b)
             (mequal? (car a) (car b))
             (mequal? (cdr a) (cdr b)))
        (let loop ((pe predicates-and-equal-procedures))
          (if (null? pe)
              (equal? a b)
              (let ((p? (car pe)))
                (if (p? a)
                    (and (p? b)
                         ((cadr pe) a b))
                    (loop (cddr pe))))))))
  mequal?)

(define list=?
  (make-equal number? =))

(list=? '(1 2 a b "test") '(1.0 2 a b "test")) ; ==> #t

(define equal-ci?
  (make-equal string? string-ci=? char? char-ci=?))

(equal-ci? '(1 2 a b "Test") '(1 2 a b "test")) ; ==> #t

(define inexact-eq-ci?
  (make-equal number? = string? string-ci=? char? char-ci=?))

(inexact-eq-ci? '(1 2 a b "test") '(1.0 2 a b "TEST")) ; ==> #t
```

Comment: Ah, that's a nice solution for lists of numbers. It sounds like then for more complicated structures, like '(a 2 (b 3)) vs. '(a 2.0 (b 3.0)), you might have to write a custom function.

Comment: @JeffAmes I've edited in an example of making a generic equal maker where you can specify how some types are to be compared.